# Update the records in a table with certain condtion

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table with 100 rows. It have id, description as columns. I have to update the column id with 15 as a break point. for eg. For 1 to 15 records I have to set Id value as 1 to 15. from 16 to 30 records, I have to set value as 1 to 15 again. i.e. for 16th record the id value should be 1.  I can manually update the data, but I am looking for a recursive method to do this.

Comment: for update I can create a column with numbers 1 to 100. so ordering couldn't be a issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulus of the `id` to achieve what you want.  Note carefully that the case where `id % 15` is 0 has to be handled; in this case you want to see 15 instead of 0.

```
UPDATE table
SET id = CASE WHEN id % 15 = 0 THEN 15 ELSE id % 15 END
```

Comment: the 15th, 30th records updated with value 0 istead of 15